# Add Sentry Log4j2 appender at runtime

Tags: log4j, apache-flink, log4j2, sentry

I've been browsing previous threads about adding Log4j2 appenders at runtime but none of them really seem to fit my scenario.

We have a longrunning Flink Job packaged into a FAT jar that we essentially submit to a running Flink cluster. We want to forward error logs to Sentry. Conveniently enough Sentry provides a [Log4j2 appender](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.sentry/sentry-log4j2/5.6.1) that I want to be able to use, but all attempts to get Log4j2 to work have failed -- going a bit crazy about this (spent days).

Since Flink (who also uses log4j2) provides a set of default logging configurations that takes precedence of any configuration files we bundle in our jar; I'm essentially left with attempting to configure the appender at runtime to see if that will make it register the appender and forward the LogEvents to it.

**As a side note**: I attempted to override the Flink provided configuration file (to essentially add the appender directly into the `Log4j2.properties` file) but Flink fails to load the plugin due to a missing dependency - `io.sentry.IHub` - which doesn't make sense since all examples/sentry docs don't mention any other dependencies outside of log4j related ones which already exists in the classpath.

I've followed the example in the log4j docs: [Programmatically Modifying the Current Configuration after Initialization](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) but the logs are not getting through to Sentry.

**SentryLog4j.scala**

```scala
package com.REDACTED.thoros.config

import io.sentry.log4j2.SentryAppender
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig

object SentryLog4j2 {
 val SENTRY_LOGGER_NAME = "Sentry"
 val SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_LEVEL: Level = Level.ALL
 val SENTRY_MINIMUM_EVENT_LEVEL: Level = Level.ERROR
 val SENTRY_DSN =
   "REDACTED"

 def init(): Unit = {
   // scalafix:off
   val loggerContext: LoggerContext =
     LogManager.getContext(false).asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]
   val configuration: Configuration = loggerContext.getConfiguration

   val sentryAppender: SentryAppender = SentryAppender.createAppender(
     SENTRY_LOGGER_NAME,
     SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_LEVEL,
     SENTRY_MINIMUM_EVENT_LEVEL,
     SENTRY_DSN,
     false,
     null
   )
   sentryAppender.start()
   configuration.addAppender(sentryAppender)
   // Creating a new dedicated logger for Sentry
   val ref: AppenderRef =
     AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("Sentry", null, null)
   val refs: Array[AppenderRef] = Array(ref)
   val loggerConfig: LoggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(
     false,
     Level.ERROR,
     "org.apache.logging.log4j",
     "true",
     refs,
     null,
     configuration,
     null
   )
   loggerConfig.addAppender(sentryAppender, null, null)
   configuration.addLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", loggerConfig)
   println(configuration.getAppenders)
   loggerContext.updateLoggers()
   // scalafix:on
 }
}
```

Then invoking the SentryLog4j.init() in the `Main` module.

```scala
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration

object Main {
  val logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger()
  sys.env.get("ENVIRONMENT") match {
    case Some("dev") | Some("staging") | Some("production") =>
      SentryLog4j2.init()
    case _ => SentryLog4j2.init() // <-- this was only added during debugging
  }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       logger.error("test") // this does not forward the logevent to the appender
    }
}
```

I think I somehow need to register the appender to loggerConfig that the rootLogger uses so that all `logger.error` statements are propogated to the configured Sentry appender?

Greatly appreciate any guidance with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an answer to how you get log4j2 and the SentryAppender to work. For anyone else that is stumbling on this problem, I'll just briefly explain what I did to get the sentry integration working.
What I eventually decided to do was drop the use of the SentryAppender and instead used the raw sentry client. Adding a wrapper class exposing the typical `debug`, `info`, `warn` and `error` methods. Then for the `warn`+ methods, I'd also send the logevent to Sentry.

This is essentially the only way I got this to work within a Flink cluster.

See example below:

```scala
sealed trait LoggerLike {
  type LoggerFn = (String, Option[Object]) => Unit
  val debug: LoggerFn
  val info: LoggerFn
  val warn: LoggerFn
  val error: LoggerFn
}


trait LazyLogging {
  @transient
  protected lazy val logger: CustomLogger =
    CustomLogger.getLogger(getClass.getName, enableSentry = true)
}


final class CustomLogger(slf4JLogger: Logger) extends LoggerLike {...your implementation...}
```

Then for each class/object (scala language at least), you'd just extend the LazyLogging trait to get a logger instance.